# Error while downloading sources in android studio for tensorflowlite

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, chrome-app-developer-tool

when ever i am clicking the download sorce in android studio for tensorflowlite file this error is showing. Here there are URLs after openeing it there is nothing. So why it is trying to download resource from there.

"Execution failed for task ':app:DownloadSources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:downloadSources_17ddbfdd-721d-4a5c-b1c6-edb7f5c67b29'.
> Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.9.0@aar.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.9.0@aar.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/2.9.0@aar/tensorflow-lite-2.9.0@aar.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/2.9.0@aar/tensorflow-lite-2.9.0@aar.pom'.
> > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
> > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

I am makng a app to image processing. which will identify the image and give output. i loaded a tensorflow lite mode.